# Finding the error in displaying the linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, linked-list

Assume we have a List class with a data member called front which is a Node pointer. Below is a member function to display the members of a list (the calling object).

It has an error. Identify and describe the error in a few
words. Then correct the error.

```
    void display ()
    {
       Node *temp= new Node;
       temp=front;
       while (temp!=NULL)
       {
         cout<<temp->data<<"\t";
         temp=temp->next;
       }
   }
```

This was one of the question in my test and I couldn't find anything wrong in the above given code. I even ran this code in the compiler and it works fine.

Can anyone tell where the error is?

Comment: Display should not have a single `new`.

Comment: @drescherjm Do I need to delete the new node which was created?

Comment: @user597654 - What are you doing with the block of memory allocated to temp after you override temp with a pointer to another object? Why are you even calling New, if you're not using the memory?

Comment: ***Do I need to delete the new node which was created?*** Don't use `new` at all in `display()` that is the bug. Allocating a new node is not wanted at all. change `Node *temp= new Node;` to `Node *temp=front;` and delete the next line. Also there should not be a delete in `display()` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node *temp = new Node; // a pointer, called temp, allocated to a new block 
                       //of memory of size Node
temp = front // the pointer to the block of memory was just overwritten, and now you 
             //don't have a pointer to the block of memory you just allocated
```

First, you don't need to call new here. Just declare the pointer and assign it at the same time.

Second, since you did call new, you've just created a memory leak, that is, you've allocated memory that now has no way of being deallocated (until the program shuts down).

Third, you should access front with an accessor method.

```
myList.GetFront() //this should return a pointer to the front of the list
```

Why? Well, what happens if you accidentally do something like:

```
front = front->next;
```

You've just lost the pointer to the front of your list, and so has every other method that uses front.

Comment: And if this is a homework question, I want credit ;)

Comment: This is not at all a homework question. I was practicing and came across this question. Thanks for clarifying the error.